# Setting ImageView from another class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set an image view from another xml file called insect_details.
Here is the code I have for doing this:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.insect_details, null);
    myHolder.insectImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.insectImage);

    InputStream ims = mContext.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(imageName);
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    myHolder.insectImage.setImageDrawable(d);
```

When I run my program insectImage is not being set to the image that is being passed to my InputStream. Am I not inflating the xml file correctly?

Comment: Any part of the code can be the problem, I suggest you use the debugger and run your code line by line then you know what lines don't work. If you can update the question after your did this.

Comment: `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.insect_details, null);` also here instead of null its better to pass the parent (the view you finally going to use as the parent of this) if you don't specify a parent all layout properties (starting with layout_) will be ignored for the root view. But this will not cause your current problem.

Comment: instead of null what could be a possible value for that?

Comment: Lets say you want to insert your view into a LinearLayout named container. you should path that instead of null, Any view group is valid.